# Unable to intercept android status bar notifications from test class

Tags: android, unit-testing, service, notifications

I have a test class that extends `ServiceTestCase<NotificationListener>` that has the following method:

```
  public void testNotificationIntercepted() throws Exception {
    bindService(new Intent(getContext(), NotificationInterceptor.class));

    // Our service is already started. Create and send a notification.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setContentTitle("Hello World");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentText("What's up?");
    Notification notif = builder.build();
    NotificationManager mgr =
        (NotificationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.notify(1492, notif);

    // Now, get our service and make sure that the notification was intercepted.
    final NotificationInterceptor iceptor = getService();

    List<NotificationBundle> notifications = iceptor.getNotificationsSeen();

    assertEquals(1, notifications.size());

    mgr.cancel(1492);
  }
```

The `NotificationInterceptor` class has a method, `onNotificationPosted()`, that essentially just adds the notifications to a list as they are posted to the device (after parsing them into a more easy-to-use format for my purposes). The problem is that this method is never invoked.

My suspicion is that the test app doesn't have the proper permissions, as it's not a separate project (I'm using AndroidStudio), and thus doesn't have it's own AndroidManifest.xml file. The app itself does have permission, both in the AndroidManifest.xml file, and in the Security->Notifications section of the Settings menu.

Is there a way around this that I can use to test the functionality of my service? (It seems to work ok within the context of the actual app... I just would like to write a test to make sure it doesn't break, as I am likely going to refactor a few things in the future).